# parsing data from v-for into a method gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have sent an array of objects of data into a child component through props, then ran a v-for and it printed the elements in the manner I want, like this

```
 <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" v-if="product.id <= 8" >
    <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
    <button @click="buyProduct">
</div>
```

and ran this method:

```
 buyProduct(){
      console.log('bought');
      const order = {
        orderId: this.product.id,
        orderName: this.product.productName,
        orderImg: this.produc.image,
        orderOriginalPrice: this.product.originalPrice,
        orderdiscountPrice: this.products.discountPrice,
        orderQuantity: this.quantity, 
        
      };
        console.log(this.products);
    }
```

but my console gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

any ideas or suggestions please? as I would like to get the values of those products I click on

Comment: can you explain what's `g` in you'r template ? also can you share you'r `data` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is the row that throws your error: `orderId: this.product.id,`

You probably never set `this.product`, a better way would be to call your `buyProduct` method with the clicked product as parameter:

```
<button @click="buyProduct(product)">buy me</button>
```

and

```
buyProduct(product) {
    ...
    orderId: product.id
    ...
}
```

Also don't combine `v-for` and `v-if` in the template (you probably already get a warning about this), instead use a `computed` property if you really want to filter the passed `products` further:

```
computed: {
   filteredProducts() {
       return this.products.filter(p => p.id <= 8)
   }
}
```

and then `v-for="product in filteredProducts"`

Comment: thank you so so so much, and yeah I know about the warning I would look into it thank you Mr TommyF

Comment: Hello Mr TommyF, can you please check this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048601/how-to-loop-through-an-array-of-data-inside-methods-vuejs/64048806?noredirect=1#comment113259904_64048806                        I'm kinda stuck and think it sth silly