# How to loop through an array of data inside methods VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

so I have an array of data called products and i'm passing it to my component in props, then using v-for order in orders to display it inside that component, when I click on a button, it takes that order and push it inside another array called orders; now I want to be able to push it only if it wasn't pushed before other wise just increment the quantity
here's my code to help:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="product in products">{{ product.name }}</div>
</template>
```

what I wanna say is if product.id = order.id don't push other quantity++;

```
props: {
  products: Array,
 orders: Array,
 }
 methods: {

   for(let i=0; i<this.orders.length; i++){
        if(product.id != this.orders[i].id || this.orders.length == 0){
           console.log('sure what the hell');
          console.log(this.orders[i].id);
          this.orders.push(product);

        } else {
          console.log('baught it before');
          console.log(this.orders[i].id);
        }
      }
```

I try it but it keeps giving me undefined
I think it is working but it needs an initial push because it keeps saying the length of orders is zero so nothing is pushed, when I enable a push outside of the if statement it doubles the pushes

Comment: Kindly provide more detail.

Comment: Code is incomplete to test

Comment: loop condition should be < not <= if starting from 0.

Comment: I have edited it please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn how to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally provide a jsfiddle or codesandbox demonstrating your problem.

You shouldn't change something that was passed in as a `prop` (read up on "one way flow").

Either have your `orders` array as a local data object in the current component or `$emit` an `addToCart` event from this component and handle the actual adding to cart in the parent by listening to this event.

Assuming your `orders` are in the local data object:

```
data() {
   return {
     orders: [
       { id: 'exists', quantity: 1 }
     ]
   }
},
methods: {
  addToCart(product) {
     let exists = this.orders.find(p => p.id == product.id)
     if(exists == -1) { // doesn't exists yet
       this.orders.push(product)
     } else {
       this.orders[exists].quantity++
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the logic you say, what I did was make a new array out of the orders prop array using .shift and it worked fine, thank you Mr TommyF this have been real helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check the value in orders, if it is returning you array having length more than 0 it means product is already added else product is not present.

```
<template>
      <div v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="index">
       <div>Name : {{ product.name }} </div>
      </div>
      <button @click="handleAdd({id:20})">Add</button>
    </template>
    
    
    props: {
      products: Array,
     orders: Array,
     }
     methods: {
       handleAdd(product){
        
          const check = this.orders.filter(item => item.id === product.id) 
          
          if(check.length === 0){
            orders.push(product)
          } else {
           // other thing
           }
        
      }
     }
```

Comment: still not working ... I think my code is good, the thing is it needs an initial push to work and I don't know how to do that I will edit my post please review it

Comment: what issue you r facing?

Comment: I just edited it please read the new function and the explanation at the bottom